# how to use pc's mic and speaker to answer the phone call on android phone using ADB command or any other method except Microsoft your phone app?

Tags: python, android, adb

I am trying to write a script by using which you call View on your pc who is calling your on your android phone, you can answer or reject the call. All by using ADB and python script. But the only problem is that I can't figure out how to make call audio played on pc(windows 10) and use pc's mic for communicating.

Comment: As far as I know that doesn't work via USB or ADB. But you can use Bluetooth to use the PC as "headset".

Comment: @Robert If i use pc as bt headset then will i be able to hear phone call audio in pc. I am asking this because some bt devices only supports multimedia audio and not calls.